# C#: Drupal database access

Tags: c#, mysql, drupal

I am making a C# program that recreates websites in offline mode for use at computers within the company, that are not connected to the internet. These offline websites are identical to their online versions, with all content displayed.

I already have a solution for websites with simple MySQL access, but I need to rewrite the program, so that it can handle Drupal based websites aswell. However, I couldn't figure out how to access Drupal's SQL database, or even what to look for.

The original program uses the website's templates (that are already rewritten in HTML), and places the data mined out of it's database in the templates. Problem is, I don't know where to look for Drupal's templates, or if there aren't any, what data should I gather from it's database.

I use MySQL Connector to reach the database with C#. Should I look for the nodes? If yes, where?

Comment: Don't go straight into the database, it's too complicated. Use the Services module instead to expose some proper resources

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go down that path you will have to sort of act like Drupal, in order to know which things to read from where. Each module installed has their own tables and functions in a particular way, so not always all the data are nodes with fields.

I you need to work with websites in offline mode, I would suggest using a portable webserver, that way you just copy the website to the root folder and run a script to copy the MySQL database as well, the point being that it's portable, you can carry it around in a flash drive and to run it, you don't need to install anything.

Again, what you want to do is possible, but it will require a tremendous amount of work and you cannot guarantee that things will behave well when you install new modules.

Another approach would be to look into the Boost module, which creates offline, static files based on the request you make to the site, and stores them in a configurable folder.

Another way: build a screenscrapper which reads the HTML from the homepage, and recursively follows the links and modify them before saving the HTML yo your local copy.

Summing it up.. avoid accessing the database yourself and try to read the HTML already rendered.